# How to authentication one website using ldap when user was authenticated on another website using ldap

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on

User is authenticated on website using LDAP.  How do I automatically authenticate the same user on another website using LDAP.  The two websites are on the same domain but separate websites- they both authenticate against same LDAP store.  Is an authentication token somehow passed from one to next?  Or the credentials or something..?  Sort of new to LDAP auth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use LDAP to achieve Single Sign On. LDAP is an 'authentication protocol' and a 'data model'.
You either need a proprietary mechanism or some standards based technology like OIDC or SAML.